# Can't figure this out, website is 'jumping'

Tags: css, hyperlink

I hope someone can help me with this, I've been searching in my CSS whats wrong but can't figure it out. 
If you look at this website: http://viversa.nl/v2/index.html , and click a bit threw the pages, you'll notice some jumping between sites. You'll notice it specially if you click from 'Projecten' to 'People' and back.
It seems "HOME" and "PROJECTEN" are the same, with both a good layout. Next to "OVER ONS", "PEOPLE", "CONTACT" and "SITEMAP" which have a good layout together aswell. But I can't figure out whats wrong and how its possible its jumping, since I simple copied the menu + logo pages + css. 
Hope someone can help me out with this!
Thanks!

Sincerely, Stefan

Comment: In which browser does this happen?

Comment: Does it happen to have something to do with the scroll bar being attached to the side of the screen, when the content of the page is too long? The first group of pages does have a scroll bar on my screen, while the second doesn't. My screen size is 1920*1080

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the project-page is longer than the screen, thus causing the vertical scroll-bar to appear. Since you are centering the layout and the scroll-bar takes up 20px or so of the space used for your site, what is considered as the center will "move" slightly when the scroll-bar appears.

To get rid of the jumping, you can force the vertical scroll-bar to always be visible:

```
html {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the browser scrollbar. Short pages that don't require scrolling have a slightly wider space available to them compared to longer pages that can be scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you got too much text for your images that are only 410px in Height, maybe delete some text or make your background images longer and added some min-height into the CSS?